# How do I customise my suspension settings?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I have just purchased a 'Fully Customisable Kit' so I can tune my suspension based off a guide I found, but I cannot find an option anywhere that will let me change the suspension settings after equipping the item in the Tuning Shop.

There must obviously be one somewhere, so where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your garage and choose your car for which you've bought the upgrade. When hovering with cursor above it, press triangle. In the options for that car, go to tuning and you will be able to make adjustments there.